# How to stop backup from including itself

Tags: backup, google-drive, macrium

I have Macrium Reflect Free that is scheduled to backup my data drive (D:). Currently my destination is an external hard drive but I want to change this to my Google Drive. My Google Drive Streaming and Cache folders are also located on my data drive (D:) and are set to online only mode.

My concern is that by storing the backup on the same drive it is uploading to Google from, Macrium could create a new image that contains the previous image before Google has a chance to upload it.

My theorised solutions

1. Ensure that the cache and offline files of Google complete before
   Macrium runs again
2. Exclude certain folders from Macrium backup in the free version
3. Use an additional hard drive for my cache or backups to stop the duplication
4. Purchase the paid version of Macrium and use folder backups instead of whole drive backups

I would prefer to avoid options 3 and 4 as they both have additional costs so does anyone know how to setup options 1 or 2, or know of an alternative solution? The cost of Google Drive is not a concern in this instance and I do not want a NAS solution

**Edit:**
Further research has shown that I cannot set the backup in Macrium to the same partition (probably because it is the smart thing to do to prevent my concerns). So looks like I will need to use a paid solution unless there are any alternative ideas

Comment: @Ramhound "the cost of Google Drive is not a concern" (read I have a student account with more than enough space)

Comment: @Ramhound the file size limit per file on a student account is 5TB